# Finding the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Consider the linear trasnformation $L:\mathbb{P^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{P^2}$ given by the formula $L(p(t))=p'(t)-tp''(t)$ Find the matrix of the linear transformation $L$ with respect to the bases $S=\{1+t^3,t+t^2,t^2−t^3,t^3\}$ and $T=\{1,t,t^2\}$. Here's what I did to attempt the problem. I found the transformation of the standard bases to be :

$L(e_1)=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

$L(e_2)=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

$L(e_3)=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

$L(e_4)=\begin{bmatrix}0\\-3\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

So I know that the matrix $A$ representing the linear transformation is :

$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-3\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I don't know what to do after this step. How do I find the matrix with respect to both bases $S$ and $T$? I apologize if I did something horrible wrong or if the answer is obvious!

Comment: Did you mean $p''(t)$ when you wrote $t''(p)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Woops! Thanks for spotting that. It's supposed to be $tp''(t)$

Comment: and $L(e_1)$ when you wrote $T(e_1)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm such an idiot, thanks.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That's why I'm confused! The exam problem has 4 elements in $S$ and 3 elements in $T$. My standard bases are $e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$,  $e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$,  $e_3=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, and  $e_4=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: That's the standard basis for $\Bbb R^4$; what's $\Bbb P^3$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So the standard basis for $\mathbb{P^3}$ is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$? I'm just writing the basis in vector form.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, $T$ is the basis for the codomain, so find what $L$ does to each element of $S$ and express the results as linear combinations of elements of $T$

Comment: Do you know what $L(s)$ is for each $s\in S$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner By expressing elements of $S$ as linear combinations of $T$, does that mean it's a change of basis problem, because that's what I'm thinking?

Comment: No, change of basis is within the same vector space; here we are expressing *images* of elements of $S$ as linear combinations of elements of $T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S=\{1+t^3,t+t^2,t^2−t^3,t^3\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb P^3$, the domain of $L$,

and $T=\{1,t,t^2\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb P^2$, the codomain of $L$.

$L$ maps the elements of $S$ to $-3t^2, 1, 3t^2, -3t^2$, respectively,

so $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\-3&0&3&-3\end{bmatrix}.$

Note that $A$ has the proper size for mapping a $4$-dimensional space to a $3$-dimensional space.

Comment: I was going about solving the question in a completely wrong way! Thank you!